# ASP.NET MVC - OutputCache - Does setting duration expire cached values?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching

Does setting the duration for OutputCache expire the cached values? Because if it does, I'm not seeing it.

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 1, Location = OutputCacheLocation.Client, VaryByParam = "none", NoStore = true)]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache["time"] == null)
        {
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache["time"] = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
```

I'm new to using OutputCache so excuse the beginner question. But it was my understanding that by specifying the duration, something was suppose to happen after the allotted time. In my code snippet above, the time persists regardless of when I refresh my view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing the OutputCache with the HttpContext.Current.Cache. The first is used to return the cached view when you hit the action, if the cache is not expired. And about that, you are right. Every 1 second it will return a new view.

However, the HttpContext.Current.Cache that you are filling with DateTime.Now, will never expire. Because you are not defining the absolute expiration

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache(v=vs.110).aspx

Doing this

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache["time"] = DateTime.Now;
```

is the same as this

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("time", DateTime.Now, null, System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration)
```

Use the Insert method and define the expiration properly, and it should work.

Comment: Could you possibly go a little deeper on "returns the cached view when you hit the action"? I'm not following exactly what you mean. What cached view will it return at that point?

Comment: From MSDN: Represents an attribute that is used to mark an action method whose output will be cached.

so would that be referring to what is being passed back to the view?

Comment: Yes. It could be a model with a list of feeds, for example. But in your case, the data is also being cached by HttpContext. Try to put the date in a viewbag instead.

Comment: I put the date inside of a view bag, and increased the duration to 10 seconds. as i refresh my web page, the time updates on each refresh. doesn't appear that the duration is working.

Comment: You shouldn't refresh. When you hit F5, the outputcache attribute doesn't work. It reloads everything. You should test with a link  pointing to this specific action

Comment: So by using OutputCache in that way, pointing to another action, it will essentially persist the data across? Is there anything to know about using a return redirectToAction() while using this? Or is it safe? I'm testing now.

Comment: It is safe. When you navigate it persists the data until the cache expires. You just can't refresh the page.

Comment: I appreciate the help. Marked this as the answer. Does it persist all variables defined within the controller? Or would I have to pass it via the View();?

Comment: it returns everything you passed to the view. Everything you passed to render it